# How do I get my compiler to be recognized by make?

Tags: makefile, cygwin

Let me start out with a disclaimer:

*I am new to writing my own makefiles and have just had a few days of research and tinkering around with my own makefile to try to figure things out.  I have also Googled this question and spent a fair amount of time looking for an answer but haven't found one.  There are many things I am inexperienced with, so if I ask a stupid question, please bear with me (and try to help me understand it).*

I have made a makefile that I have been testing out to see if my understanding is correct, and so far everything here makes sense and works until it gets to `$(CC)`.  I'm on windows 7 using cygwin64 terminal and it gives this output after I type make:

```
make: tricore-gcc: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:20: test_eeprom.o] Error 127
```

So **why can't it recognize my compiler? Why does it say "Command not found?"**  I know the compiler is installed because I have used it for existing projects on my computer and just now am starting to write my own makefile and try to use it.  I have even seen in other makefiles that were made by someone previous to me that they define the compiler the same way as me in the makefile.

For reference, here is my makefile:

```
#Test module Makefile

#compiler
CC = tricore-gcc

#path to MBD header files
MBDPATH = ../../../../../../Application/MBD/build/test_ert_rtw

#where the source code is
SRC = Src

#object files to be made
DS_OBJ = test_eeprom.o test_gd.o test_task.o \
          sct_conf.o unimportant_name.o


#rule to make test eeprom object
test_eeprom.o: $(SRC)/test_eeprom.c $(SRC)/test_eeprom.h $(SRC)/test_task.h \
                    $(MBDPATH)/test.h
    $(CC) -c test_eeprom.
```

Comment: Where is your compiler installed? Is that directory in the `PATH`? Have you tied using the full path to the compiler?

Comment: If, at the same prompt where you typed `make`, you type something like `tricore-gcc --version` does it work or do you get the same "command not found" error?  If you get the same error then you need to get that working first (by modifying $PATH most likely as Joachim mentions).  If the shell can't find your compiler, then make can't find it either.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg If by PATH you mean the system environment variable, then yes my compiler is in there. http://screencast.com/t/CHojh3OPqqgC

Comment: @MadScientist ok I tried that and it is the same error (http://screencast.com/t/3JuF7a7HQOR) I guess the question is now if my Path system variable is the same PATH that you are both mentioning.  I'm thinking it is but I'm not sure why mine isn't all caps

Comment: This is a Windows vs. cygwin thing.  On Windows, the environment variable is named `Path`.  In UNIX systems, the environment variable is named `PATH` (all caps).  Cygwin is an attempt to have a UNIX environment running on Windows.  I don't use Windows much and I don't use Cygwin at all but a bit of Google leads me to believe Cygwin tries to import the Windows Path value and set PATH.  You can run `echo $PATH` in Cygwin to see what you have.  Maybe you're resetting it somehow.  Anyway, you should remove the "makefile" and "c" tags since this is not a make or compiler issue.

Comment: @MadScientist I did echo $PATH and verified that it is missing the path to my compiler.  now I only need to figure out why it appears in my Windows Path and not in the Cygwin PATH.  thanks for your help so far, I'm learning new things!

Comment: After closing and reopening the cygwin terminal, the PATH is now updated to reflect the changes I made in the windows system environment variable "Path" and it now recognizes my compiler.  Guess this is just a downside of using cygwin instead of an actual UNIX environment. Thanks for your help figuring this out!

Comment: the PATH is set during shell startup. If you change the PATH in a process does not impact the other running processes; this is valid in ANY enviroment Windows or Unix. You can of course change it in at any time for a give process